DSI calculation using socialindices R error
I'm trying to calculate DSI scores between male-females dyads using the socialindices by Christof Neumann package. I have three dataframes: one containing the behavioural observations, one the observation time and another the presence file. Here are their structures:
> str(observations)
tibble [476 × 6] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
 $ date    : Date[1:476], format: "2022-10-20" "2022-10-14" "2022-10-14" "2022-09-20" ...
 $ focal   : chr [1:476] "Sho" "Sho" "Sho" "Buk" ...
 $ actor   : chr [1:476] "Ginq" "Sho" "Ndaw" "Ginq" ...
 $ receiver: chr [1:476] "Sho" "Ndaw" "Sho" "Buk" ...
 $ beh     : chr [1:476] "Approach" "Approach" "Groom.focal" "Contact.focal" ...
 $ dur     : int [1:476] NA NA 128 661 223 899 434 NA 19 NA ...

> str(ot)
'data.frame':   209 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ focal: chr  "Buk" "Buk" "Buk" "Buk" ...
 $ date : chr  "2022-06-07" "2022-06-11" "2022-06-15" "2022-06-17" ...
 $ OT   : int  1204 1212 1212 1200 1200 1202 1205 635 1204 963 ...

> str(pres)
'data.frame':   374 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ date: chr  "2022-01-03" "2022-01-04" "2022-01-05" "2022-01-06" ...
 $ Buk : int  1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Ginq: int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Ndaw: int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Sho : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...

Since I am interested in seeing how male-female relationships evolve over time, I have chosen to have my males as my focal individuals. That means that in this particular group, I have two focal individuals (Buk and Sho), and three potential partners for each.
This is the code that I'd like to run:
scores <- DSI(observations, ot.source = ot, presence = pres, onlyfocaldyads = F, limit2focalnonfocal = T, duration.NA.treatm = "count")

But I keep getting this error:
Error in strptime(xx, ff, tz = "GMT") : input string is too long

All my date columns are dates and their range is the same. The same calculations worked before when I used all observations, but that doesn't really serve my purpose. If anyone has any idea why this is not working, I'd be very grateful!

DSI() only accepts data.frame() objects, and your observations object is a tibble(). Below is a reprex that generates your error, followed by a working solution:
# install.packages("remotes")
remotes::install_github("gobbios/socialindices")
library(socialindices2)

# Load sample data
data(dataset3)

# Create representative dataframes
observations <- tibble(dataset3[[1]])

ot <- data.frame(dataset3[[2]])

pres <- data.frame(dataset3[[3]])

# Caculate dyadic CSI
scores <- DSI(observations,
              ot.source = ot,
              presence = pres,
              onlyfocaldyads = F,
              limit2focalnonfocal = T,
              duration.NA.treatm = "count")
# Error in strptime(xx, ff, tz = "GMT") : input string is too long

# Convert observations to df
observations <- data.frame(observations)

# Caculate dyadic CSI again
scores <- DSI(observations,
              ot.source = ot,
              presence = pres,
              onlyfocaldyads = F,
              limit2focalnonfocal = T,
              duration.NA.treatm = "count")


scores
#   i1 i2 type  dyad  dot cores appr  gro prox supp   appr.rt    gro.rt   prox.rt   supp.rt     DSI     zDSI
# 1  a  d  FNF a_@_d 3877   119    1 2190 1805    1 0.6675996 5.2571514 4.3288838 0.7880743 2.76043  1.17610
# 2  a  n  FNF a_@_n 3208    98    0  325  192    0 0.0000000 0.9428686 0.5564952 0.0000000 0.37484 -0.56118
# 3  a  v  FNF a_@_v 3877   119    0  117   67    2 0.0000000 0.2808615 0.1606843 1.5761486 0.50442 -0.38591
# 4  d  f  FNF d_@_f 6658   200    2   87  195    3 0.7774958 0.1216123 0.2723236 1.3767035 0.63703 -0.24598
# 5  f  n  FNF f_@_n 6026   179    2  580  421    2 0.8590387 0.8957793 0.6496022 1.0140604 0.85462 -0.11512
# 6  f  v  FNF f_@_v 6658   200    7  342  569    0 2.7212355 0.4780623 0.7946264 0.0000000 0.99848  0.07002
# 7  d  j  FNF d_@_j 4162   119    0   92  459    1 0.0000000 0.2057254 1.0254279 0.7341096 0.49132 -0.41839
# 8  j  n  FNF j_@_n 3481    98    2   96  345    4 1.4870920 0.2566666 0.9215303 3.5109037 1.54405  0.55217
# 9  j  v  FNF j_@_v 4162   119    4  251  130    0 2.4875384 0.5612726 0.2904262 0.0000000 0.83481 -0.07171


Thank you very much! I completely missed that it was a tibble. Using it as a dataframe solved the issue!
